# Cast to ObjectID failed for value (Front end side problem)

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, http, postman

So I have been given an API to which I need to send a post request to create a task within a list, but when I try to send the request, I get the following error (I am trying it in postman).

The following is the schema of a post request body I need to send to the API, and the image is the request I am sending with the postman (I need to use the x-www-form-urlencoded because otherwise, it is not working)

```
{
   title: { type: String,required:true},
   description: String,
   done:Boolean,
   date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   list:{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'List'
}
```

[image]

So can you please help me with this?
I get the following error.

```
Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"Daily Tasks\" at path \"list\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is expecting you to pass the id of a List, not its name.
It's probably expecting you to do an other API call before to get that id.

It should look like this: "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"

Additionally, you can look at the documentation of MongoDB for information about the ObjectId format: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: so how can I send the list's id if I have its name?
do i need to send a get req and then filter the list I want by name and find its id?

Comment: This is an implementation details that we cannot really know, and you should probably reach to whoever is developing this API.

But my short educated guess would be: yes